# powershell split into hashtable

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to split string that i got from jira rest api, and i can't find a good way to do it.
API returns this kind of object

> com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@3b306c49[id=2792,rapidViewId=920,state=CLOSED,name=ABI
>   Reports/Support sprint
>   12,startDate=2018-09-11T09:45:26.622+02:00,endDate=2018-09-27T22:00:00.000+02:00,completeDate=2018-09-28T08:15:41.088+02:00,sequence=2792] com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@c518022[id=2830,rapidViewId=920,state=ACTIVE,name=ABI
>   Reports/Support sprint
>   13,startDate=2018-09-28T08:30:26.785+02:00,endDate=2018-10-16T20:30:00.000+02:00,completeDate=,sequence=2830]

What I do with it is

```
$sprints = $issue.fields.customfield_10012 | Select-String -Pattern '\x5b(.*)\x5d' | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Where $issue.fields.customfield_10012 is the field returned from REST API

This gives me object striped of exesse data which i can convert to hash table using this

```
Foreach ($sprint in $sprints) {
  Try {
    #assign values to variable
    $sprint = $sprint -split ',' | Out-String
    $sprint = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $sprint
    [int]$sId = $sprint.id
    $sName = "N'" + $sprint.name.Replace("'", "''") + "'"
    #insert into sql using Invoke-Sqlcmd
  }
  Catch {
    #Write log msg into log table about error in Staging of the worklog for the ticket
    $logMsg = "Staging sprint ($sId) for ticket ($key): $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host $logMsg
  }
}
```

But my users are creative and one of the sprint's name was "Sprint 11 - AS,SS,RS" - which breaks my -split ',' and convert to hash table.

Any idea how to split this string to proper hash table?

> com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@3b306c49[id=2792,rapidViewId=920,state=CLOSED,name=ABI
>   Reports/Support sprint
>   12,startDate=2018-09-11T09:45:26.622+02:00,endDate=2018-09-27T22:00:00.000+02:00,completeDate=2018-09-28T08:15:41.088+02:00,sequence=2792] com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@c518022[id=2830,rapidViewId=920,state=ACTIVE,name=Sprint
>   11 -
>   AS,SS,RS,startDate=2018-09-28T08:30:26.785+02:00,endDate=2018-10-16T20:30:00.000+02:00,completeDate=,sequence=2830]

Comment: Do you need to keep "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@c518022"? Is there 2 distinct object in that string text and likely to be a variable amount in your real data?

Comment: Would also like to know how _exactly_ those strings exist? one record per line? contains miscellaneous newlines as we see in edit?

Comment: Also how are you getting this data? presumably if it comes from a rest api it should be retrieved as object already?

Comment: @Matt Based on how they're accessing the return, it does appear to already be an object.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Indeed it does. Should stop trying to do SO and my actual job at the same time.

Comment: @Matt how else will you free up your brain to put work problems on the backburner?  @OP: I suggest checking out `ConvertFrom-String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on commas *followed by* a word with an equal sign

Working with each of those records on their own line (if this does not match the source data you can still use the logic below) we do a match to split up the data inside the braces [] from that outside. Then we so a split on that internal data as discussed above, with a positive lookahead, to get the hashtables.

```
$lines = "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@3b306c49[id=2792,rapidViewId=920,state=CLOSED,name=ABI Reports/Support sprint 12,startDate=2018-09-11T09:45:26.622+02:00,endDate=2018-09-27T22:00:00.000+02:00,completeDate=2018-09-28T08:15:41.088+02:00,sequence=2792]", 
"com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@c518022[id=2830,rapidViewId=920,state=ACTIVE,name=Sprint 11 - AS,SS,RS,startDate=2018-09-28T08:30:26.785+02:00,endDate=2018-10-16T20:30:00.000+02:00,completeDate=,sequence=2830]"


$lines | Where-Object{$_ -match "^(?<sprintid>.*)\[(?<details>.*)\]"} | ForEach-Object{
    $Matches.details -split ",(?=\w+=)" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
}
```

If we use the `[pscustomobject]` type accelerator when can get an object set right from that.

`id           : 2792
startDate    : 2018-09-11T09:45:26.622+02:00
completeDate : 2018-09-28T08:15:41.088+02:00
sequence     : 2792
name         : ABI Reports/Support sprint 12
rapidViewId  : 920
endDate      : 2018-09-27T22:00:00.000+02:00
state        : CLOSED`

id           : 2830
startDate    : 2018-09-28T08:30:26.785+02:00
completeDate : 
sequence     : 2830
name         : Sprint 11 - AS,SS,RS
rapidViewId  : 920
endDate      : 2018-10-16T20:30:00.000+02:00
state        : ACTIVE

I have more experience with `ConvertFrom-StringData` however as [TheIncorrigible1 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836605/powershell-split-into-hashtable/52837399#comment92590342_52836605)... [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1) is also powerful and can reduce some legwork here.

Comment: In the end, it all comes down to regular expressions. That is exactly what i needed. Actually what I needed was this regex ",(?=\w+=)", but I really need to understand what is going on in the first regex